# Is there a way to print the bit representation of an object?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm using something like the following. Is there a better way?

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Person) ; i++) {
    const char &cr = *((char*)personPtr + i);
    cout << bitset<CHAR_BIT>(cr);
}
```

Comment: `Person` may contain padding bits. Better to use a `serialize_as_binary` method in `class Person`. Also you may end up out of bound memory with this method. For example if `sizeof` the `Person` and `long long` are 4 and 8 respectively.

Comment: Won't those padding be included in the result? since I'm printing word by word?

Comment: But padding bits are useless and may be confusing. Printing equal `Person` objects may print 2 different bit pattern.

Comment: If you're going to do it, do it with a type/size everyone can agree on, like uint8_t.

Comment: @MikeSeymour By using a bitset but he is already doing that so I deleted my suggestion.

Comment: @Robinson Has a point. You should use char as your struct will be divisible by it, but may not be divisible by long's size.

Comment: Yep. Forgot it. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite right after your edit.  std::bitset<n>, n is the number of bits.  sizeof(x) is the number of bytes.  So it needs to be CHAR_BIT, which will give you the number of bits in a CHAR.

Comment: @SankaD: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so there's no point dividing by that. `CHAR_BIT` would be better than 8, since bytes don't necessarily have 8 bits. Also, it's best not to keep changing the code in the question, since that can invalidate answers that refer to it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll add from below then.

Comment: You need to decide what representation you want. There's no use us guessing whether you want padding or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest to provide a `serialize_as_binary` utility in your `Person` class.

```
template<typename T>
void serialize_as_bin(const T &t, ostream& os) {
  const unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&t);
  for(size_t s = 0; s < sizeof t; ++s, ++p) serialize_as_bin(*p, os);
}

template<>
void serialize_as_bin(const unsigned char &t, ostream& os) {
  // Code to serialize one byte
  std::bitset<CHAR_BIT> x(t);
  os << x;
}

struct Person {
  A a;
  B b;

  ostream& serialize_as_binary(ostream& os) {
    serialize_as_bin(a, os);
    serialize_as_bin(b, os);
    return os;
  }
  void deserialize_from_binary() {
    // Similar stuff if required
    ...
  }
};
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/TjrQcU)

Comment: I think you meant `*(p+s)` in the loop.

Comment: @MohitJain Can you explain a bit about the danger/assumptions in my method? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't notice you changing `long` to `char *`. With `long` or `long long` you would face strict aliasing issues.

Comment: This is good in parts, but I don't like how you've hardcoded that it outputs to `std::cout`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the comment. I just wanted to give an idea. My favorite would be to serialize to a stream. I will update it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This is meant as a simple non-serious solution that doesn't care about padding. Prints the bytes and bits from right to left.

```
template<typename T>
void PrintBits(const T& o) {
  for (size_t i = sizeof(o) - 1; i < sizeof(o); --i)
    std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&o)[i]);
}
```